# Automatically restarting a Python program

Tags: python, systemd

I have a very long running Python program that I can manually start (and stop) from the command line.  I do not want this program started automatically during system boot.  But, after I manually start it running, I would like a way for my Pi to restart this Python program running again if it ever stops or exits for any reason, even if I'm logged out of my Pi.  How can I do this?

Answer (score 2):

If you have something you want to run for a long period you can use a terminal multiplexer like screen or tmux. They will continue to run after you have been disconnected from your Pi. As for keeping a process running for long running jobs you will want to [wrap the command in a simple shell script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/696839/how-do-i-write-a-bash-script-to-restart-a-process-if-it-dies). If you want to keep it a pure python code base you may want the process to run as a daemon. This is a great and [very well documented example](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/278731/)